# Change radio button value based on ajax response

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button, promise, jsviews

I an binding an array of objects with JSViews with a default object. I am showing the default one with a radio button. When I want to make another object as default, I need to make an ajax call and change it to the default object only when the call succeeds with a predefined status.I am using promises for ajax requests.I know if I return false in the function, the radio button status will not change.I tried something like this but it doesn't work.I am assuming since I am returning the promise, it does not resolve to true or false by the time it is returned. How can it be accomplished?

```
<input type="radio" name="default" data-link="checked{:isDefaultObj} {on ~setAsDefault}">
```

JS

```
setAsDefault:function(){
  return service.setAsDefaultObj('123').then(function(response){
        return response; //response is either true or false;
    },function(response){
       return response;
   });
 }
```

Comment: If the answer below worked for you, could you "accept" it? Thanks... (It's away of acknowledging the time and effort spent answering you!)

Comment: @BorisMoore: I am so sorry..I was not able to respond on the solution as I was working on unrelated projects for couple of weeks...I will try the solution and update the status. Your timely response is very much appreciated. Apologies for not following up. Will make sure I do that in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `~setAsDefault` - you can return false so the default click action to check that input is skipped.

Then I would suggest associating a data-linked property with the radio buttons group, so you can observably set the new one/original one after your promise returns successful/error.

Here is an example for data-linking to `selectedCar`, with deferred setting of the appropriate value.

Either use one-way data-linking:

```
<label><input name="cars" type="radio" value="none" data-link="{:selectedCar} {on getAjax 'none'}"/>
  None</label><br/>
<label><input name="cars" type="radio" value="vlv" data-link="{:selectedCar} {on getAjax 'vlv'}"/>
  Volvo</label><br/>
<label><input name="cars" type="radio" value="frd" data-link="{:selectedCar} {on getAjax 'frd'}"/>
  Ford</label><br/><br/>
```

Or use your `checked{...}` approach

```
<label><input name="cars2" type="radio" value="none" data-link="checked{:selectedCar==='none'} {on getAjax 'none'}"/>
  None</label><br/>
<label><input name="cars2" type="radio" value="vlv" data-link="checked{:selectedCar==='vlv'}  {on getAjax 'vlv'}"/>
  Volvo</label><br/>
<label><input name="cars2" type="radio" value="frd" data-link="checked{:selectedCar==='frd'}  {on getAjax 'frd'}"/>
  Ford</label><br/><br/>
```

In each case use the following code approach:

```
var data = {
  selectedCar: "frd",
  getAjax: function(val) {
    var sel = data.selectedCar;
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: "../TEST" + val + ".html",
      timeout: 5000,
      success: function(){
        $.observable(data).setProperty("selectedCar", val);
      },
      error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
        $.observable(data).setProperty("selectedCar", val);
        $.observable(data).setProperty("selectedCar", sel);
      }
    });
    return false;
  }
};
```